# Node.js GET request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm making an API and in one of my GET methods i need to make a GET request to another API. In order to do that first i need to select the url depending on a parameter in the route.
My code is something like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const request = require('request');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/get/:keyword?', (req,res) =>{

        let keyword = req.params.keyword;
        
        let url;
        if(keyword == ""){
            url = 'some string';
        }else{
            url = 'another string';
        }

        request(url, {json:true}, (error, response, body) => {
            if(error){
                res.send("Something went wrong");
            }else{
                res.send(body);
            }
        });

});
```

However, i'm getting an error like if the "if" block is being ignored.
I read some sites and I believe it's because the request function is asynchronous, but I don't know how i can solve it.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What **exactly** is the error?

Comment: @Phil It’s not exactly an error, but the response is empty or invalid. However if I define the url being equal to any string I correctly get a valid response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've mentioned the request you are making is `asynchronous` you need to handle it within an async function because you don't know when it resolves.

```
router.get('/get/:keyword?', async (req,res) => {
    let keyword = req.params.keyword;
    
    let url;
    if(keyword === "") {
        url = 'some string';
    } else {
        url = 'another string';
    }

    try {
      const res = await request(url, {json:true});
      res.send(res)
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
});
```

or you can use `.then()` style to handle the promises if you don't want to use `async..await` syntax

```
router.get('/get/:keyword?', (req,res) => {

    let keyword = req.params.keyword;
    
    let url;
    if(keyword === ""){
        url = 'some string';
    }else{
        url = 'another string';
    }

    request(url, {json:true}).then(res => {
       // do something with the result
       res.send(res.json())
     }).then(err => console.log(err))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

May it be because you forgot to close the function with the ')' at the end of the router.get? like

```
router.get('/get/:keyword?', (req,res) => {

        let keyword = req.params.keyword;
        
        let url;
        if(keyword == ""){
            url = 'some string';
        }else{
            url = 'another string';
        }

        request(url, {json:true}, (error, response, body) => {
            if(error){
                res.send("Something went wrong");
            }else{
                res.send(body);
            }
        });

}); // <--- here you missed the ')'
```

Comment: Oh sorry! That was a typo on the question. I do have the ) at the end

Comment: Oh, no problem, have you debugged what comes in keyword? maybe if you initialize it with the value using a ternary operator would work? something like:

let url = keyword == "" ? 'some string' : 'another string';

Comment: It didnt solve the problem directly, but it help me to find the solution!
The problem was that the keyword was never empty, it was set as undefined. So all this time i was searching with the query=undefined. 

Thanks!!

Comment: Glad it barely helped haha, share the solution once you have it! ^^